# Laravel 5.2 Cron Job Doesn't Work Automatic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my kernel :

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\AdvertiseTasks::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('advertise:delete')->everyMinute();
}
```

This is my Command Handle

```
 public function handle()
{
    Advertise::where('expired', '<=', Carbon::now()->createFromTime(23, 59, 59))->delete();
    $this->info('All Expired Advertise Are Deleted Successfully!' . Carbon::now());
    Log::info('All Expired Advertise Are Deleted Successfully!');
}
```

and i run this command on my project :

```
cd /wamp/www/project
php artisan schedule:run
```

and I look at my log when I press enter it was OK. log changed but after some minutes log doesn't change and Crone wasn't start automatic. how can i do?

Comment: What does your cron entry look like?

Comment: You still didn't post your cron entry. You have to have an entry in crontab in order to run the command. Something like `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/project/artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1` -- do you have that set up?

Comment: @Samsquanch Sorry My cronetab command doest'n work,and how can i add this to you said ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually register the cronjob. All you're doing is running it once.

It's always worth checking the documentation, as your solution is actually in it:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling